# Virtual keyboard with multiple inputs and auto jump to next input after reaching maxlength?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

i need to create a virtual keyboard with multiple inputs and auto jump to next input after reaching maxlength (1)... on my code there are 2 inputs that i should fill but i can only fill the first input and not the second one. and auto jump to the next field should work too, can anybody help me with this ?

(there are 2 actif inputs and the others are (readonly) and the user needs to tap the digit and it should fill the first actif input with 1 number and automatically jump to the next actif input and tap again on another digit and it should write another number and that's all)

Here is my code.

```
<body onload="load();"> 
<div class="firma-box-resultado" style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
        <input type="text" id="" class="num-coordenada" readonly="">
        <input type="text" id="tbInput" class="num-coordenada active completo" maxlength="1">
        <input type="text" id="tbInput" class="num-coordenada active completo" maxlength="1">
        <input type="text" id="" class="num-coordenada" readonly="">
        <input type="text" id="" class="num-coordenada" readonly="">
        <input type="text" id="" class="num-coordenada" readonly=""></div>


    </div>


<div id="VirtualKey">
            <input class="clave" id="btn1" type="button" onclick="input(this);" value="3" style="margin-right:1px;" />
            <input class="clave" id="btn2" type="button" onclick="input(this);" value="8" style="margin-right:1px;" />
            <input class="clave" id="btn3" type="button" onclick="input(this);" value="7" style="margin-right:1px;" />
            <input class="clave" id="btn4" type="button" onclick="input(this);" value="0" style="margin-right:1px;" />
            <input class="clave" id="btn5" type="button" onclick="input(this);" value="2" style="margin-bottom:5px;" />
            <br />
            <input class="clave" id="btn6" type="button" onclick="input(this);" value="1" style="margin-right:1px;" />
            <input class="clave" id="btn7" type="button" onclick="input(this);" value="9" style="margin-right:1px;" />
            <input class="clave" id="btn8" type="button" onclick="input(this);" value="4" style="margin-right:1px;" />
            <input class="clave" id="btn9" type="button" onclick="input(this);" value="5" style="margin-right:1px;" />
            <input class="clave" id="btn0" type="button" onclick="input(this);" value="6" style="margin-right:1px;" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <input id="btnDel" type="button" value="Borrar" onclick="del();" />
        </div>



<script type="text/javascript">
        function input(e) {
            var tbInput = document.getElementById("tbInput");
            tbInput.value = tbInput.value + e.value;
            tbInput2.value = tbInput2.value + e.value;
        }


        function del() {
            var tbInput = document.getElementById("tbInput");
            tbInput.value = tbInput.value.substr(0, tbInput.value.length - 1);
        }




        function load() {
            var array = new Array();

            while (array.length < 10) {
                var temp = Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
                if (!contain(array, temp)) {
                    array.push(temp);
                }
            }
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                var btn = document.getElementById("btn" + i);
                btn.value = array[i];
            }
        }


        let $inputs = $('.firma-box-resultado input').on('input', e => {
          let $input = $(e.target);
          let index = $inputs.index($input);
          
          if ($input.val().length >= $input.prop('maxlength')) {
            $inputs.eq(index + 1).prop('enabled', false).focus();
          } 
        });

        </script>

</body>
```

Comment: You posted this same question and code yesterday (apparently deleted now).  And the answer is the same as yesterday:  The inputs can't have the same ID "tbInput".  There are multiple other mistakes too.  Variable tbInput2 is never initialized, the "contains()" method is not defined, etc.

Comment: @Yogi Can you help me with my code please ? and tell me how the entire correct code should be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this :

To expand the number of inputs, check the length of the input by order if the first is 0 (empty) the fill it if not check the next one ...

```
if (tbInput.val().length == 0) {
   tbInput.val(e.value);
}
else if (tbInput2.val().length == 0) 
   tbInput2.val(e.value);
else {
   tbInput3.val(e.value);
}
```

```js
function input(e) {
            var tbInput = $("#tbInput");
            var tbInput2 = $("#tbInput2");
            var tbInput3 = $("#tbInput3");
            
            if (tbInput.val().length == 0) {
              tbInput.val(e.value);
            }
            else if (tbInput2.val().length == 0) 
              tbInput2.val(e.value);
            else {
              tbInput3.val(e.value);
            }
        }


        function del() {
            var tbInput = $(".num-coordenada"); 
            tbInput.val('');
        }




        function load() {
            var array = new Array();

            while (array.length < 10) {
                var temp = Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
                if (!contain(array, temp)) {
                    array.push(temp);
                }
            }
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                var btn = document.getElementById("btn" + i);
                btn.value = array[i];
            }
        }


          let $inputs = $('.firma-box-resultado input').on('input', e => {
          let $input = $(e.target);
          let index = $inputs.index($input);
          
          if ($input.val().length >= $input.prop('maxlength')) {
            $inputs.eq(index + 1).prop('enabled', false).focus();
          } 
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="load();">

    <div class="firma-box-resultado" >
    
        <input type="text" id="tbInput" class="num-coordenada active completo" maxlength="1">
        <input type="text" id="tbInput2" class="num-coordenada active completo" maxlength="1">
        <input type="text" id="tbInput3" class="num-coordenada" readonly="">
        <input type="text" class="num-coordenada" readonly="">
        <input type="text" class="num-coordenada" readonly="">
    </div>


<div id="VirtualKey">
            <input class="clave" id="btn1" type="button" onclick="input(this);" value="3" style="margin-right:1px;" />
            <input class="clave" id="btn2" type="button" onclick="input(this);" value="8" style="margin-right:1px;" />
            <input class="clave" id="btn3" type="button" onclick="input(this);" value="7" style="margin-right:1px;" />
            <input class="clave" id="btn4" type="button" onclick="input(this);" value="0" style="margin-right:1px;" />
            <input class="clave" id="btn5" type="button" onclick="input(this);" value="2" style="margin-bottom:5px;" />
            <br />
            <input class="clave" id="btn6" type="button" onclick="input(this);" value="1" style="margin-right:1px;" />
            <input class="clave" id="btn7" type="button" onclick="input(this);" value="9" style="margin-right:1px;" />
            <input class="clave" id="btn8" type="button" onclick="input(this);" value="4" style="margin-right:1px;" />
            <input class="clave" id="btn9" type="button" onclick="input(this);" value="5" style="margin-right:1px;" />
            <input class="clave" id="btn0" type="button" onclick="input(this);" value="6" style="margin-right:1px;" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <input id="btnDel" type="button" value="Borrar" onclick="del();" />
        </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i needed thak you so much !!